# Rails - Find By with 2 fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in a controller

```
def update
    @permission = Permission.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id])
```

But I want it to also find by another param, `project_id`

How can I do something like this in Rails?

```
@permission = Permission.find_by_user_id_and_project_id(params[:user_id],params[:user_id])
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Rails 4 introduces the find_by method:

```
Permission.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], project_id: params[:project_id])
```

Comment: Is this syntax susceptible to SQL Injection?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. It's a bit confusing when it is ok to use params[:attribute] and when it's not.

Comment: It's not susceptible to injection - the only time you are in danger of SQL injection is when you interpolate a submitted param directly into a string meant to be used in a query - like `ModelName.where("attribute = '#{params[:attribute]}'")`. There are cases where you need a custom query you can't create with ActiveRecord query builders, but in those cases you can use the following syntax: `ModelName.where("attribute = ?", params[:attribute])`

Answer (score 67):

Yes, you can do finds in a bunch of ways.

Your example below works:

`@permission = Permission.find_by_user_id_and_project_id(params[:user_id],params[:project_id])`

-- Note your example had two user_ids

In rails 2.x you can also use conditions

```
@permission = Permission.find(:conditions=>["user_id=? and project_id=?", params[:user_id], params[:project_id]])
```

And in Rails 3, you can be cool like:

```
@permission = Permission.where(:user_id=>params[:user_id]).where(:project_id=>params[:project_id]).first
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the first one though... A lot cleaner.

Comment: the last one is the rails 3 way... unless put into a scope.

Comment: Agree with DGM here, scopes are great.... Permission.for(@user).for(@project).first is a good for code readability

Comment: Isn't the Rails3 version open to SQL Injection because you pass params directly into the where condition?
As far as I know, the .find method is sanitized.

Comment: @BookOfGreg it's all the same find method. as long as you don't create the SQL strings yourself, it's protected. Don't: "user_id=#{params[:id]}". do: "user_id=?", params[:id]

Comment: BTW in rails 4 find_by_user_id_and_project_id is deprecated

Comment: What if I wanted it to be an OR but still using multiple columns?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@permission = Permission.find(:conditions => ['user_id = ? and project_id = ?', params[:user_id], params[:project_id]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails 3 way with scopes:

```
scope :by_user_id_and_project_id, lambda {|user_id,project_id| 
    where(:user_id=>user_id).where(:project_id=>project_id])
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
@permission = Permission.by_user_id_and_project_id(params[:user_id],params[:project_id])
```