# Rails scope with array as argument Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'd have two attributes in my `Member` model, `first_name` and `last_name`. My requirement is that I will be given an array of full names:

```
["Jane Doe", "John Doe", "Foo Bar"]
```

And, for each element I need to:

1. Parse each element into first and last names
2. Find each Member record by `first_name` and `last_name` (if it exists)

I've tried to create this within a model scope, like this:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :find_by_full_name, -> (full_name) { |full_name|
      first_name = full_name.split(' ').first
      last_name = full_name.split(' ').last
      where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
  }
```

It works with a string, but not an array.  I reviewed this article -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8155276/4379077.  It looks like Rails should detect if it's an array or a string, and handle each type accordingly.  After a bunch or console attempts (inc. turning the element to string) I'm at a loss of what I'm doing wrong, or maybe I should be going at in a different way besides creating a scope.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a scope is just syntactic sugar for a Class method anyways, I would recommend just creating it as a class method and the whole thing becomes much easier/cleaner:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  self.find_by_full_name(array_of_names)
    members = []

    array_of_names.each do |name|
      split_names = name.split(' ')
      members.push(Member.find_by_first_name_and_last_name(split_names.first, split_names.last))
    end

    members.compact
  end

end
```

---

#### UPDATE

And then you could even extend the capabilities of it easily (one additional line) if you wanted it to be able to accept either a single name or an array of names:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  self.find_by_full_name(names)
    members = []
    names = [names] if names.is_a?(String)

    names.each do |name|
      split_names = name.split(' ')
      members.push(Member.find_by_first_name_and_last_name(split_names.first, split_names.last))
    end

    members.compact
  end

end
```

---

#### NOTE

Not sure if you're familiar with `.compact` but that will accomplish the `"if it exists"` portion of your question. The `Member.find_by...` will push a `nil` value onto `members` if there isn't a match, and then `.compact` will remove the `nil` values from `members`.

Comment: Great answer @jeffdill2.  I appreciate the extra line!

Comment: This approach seems to introduce a N+1 query

Comment: @tobmatth yeah, it definitely would. I'll see what I can do to make it more efficient. Of course, it may be moot for the OP depending on their use case, but it'd be a fun exercise anyways. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to look up your members via this array of names?

You could also use something like

```
full_names.each do |name|
  first = name.split(" ").first
  last = name.split(" ").last
  variable = Member.find_by_first_name_and_last_name(:first_name => first,
                                                    :last_name => last)
  # member_records[] << variable 
  # or whatever you're doing with them next.

end
```

You can request "find_by" with multiple arguments 
as such
[Rails - Find By with 2 fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936621/rails-find-by-with-2-fields)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid N+1 queries-which I recommend-there is a one-off solution. You can concatenate the first and last name within the SQL query and compare it to the given arguments.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  space = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')
  concat_op = '||' # check which operator your database uses
  first_name_space = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new(concat_op, arel_table[:first_name], space)
  first_name_space_last_name = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new(concat_op, first_name_space, arel_table[:last_name])

  scope :find_by_full_name, -> (full_name) { where(first_name_space_last_name.in(full_name)) }
end
```

This works for single strings and arrays as arguments.

**NOTE** Check what operator your database uses as concatenate operator and adapt accordingly. This example assumes `||`, which would work for PostgreSQL and SQLite databases.

Answer (score -1):

Not very elegant, but how about

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :find_by_full_name, -> (*args) {
    conds = []
    conds << args.count.times.map { "first_name = ? AND last_name = ?" }.join(' OR ')
    args.map { |arg| arg.split(' ') }.flatten.each { |e| conds << e }
    where(conds)
  }

end
```